# Lambda function type creep

Tags: c++, lambda, casting, type-conversion

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
tbb::blocked_range<int> range(0, a.rows);
uint64_t positive = tbb::parallel_reduce(range, 0, // <- initial value
  [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r, uint64_t v)->uint64_t {
    for (int y = r.begin(); y < r.end(); ++y) {
        auto rA = a[y], rB = b[y];
        for (int x = 0; x < a.cols; ++x) {
            auto A = rA[x], B = rB[x];
            for (int l = y; l < a.rows; ++l) {
                auto rAA = a[l], rBB = b[l];
                for (int m = x; m < a.cols; ++m) {
                    if (l == y && m == x)
                        continue;
                    auto AA = rAA[m], BB = rBB[m];
                    if ((A == AA) && (B == BB))
                        v++; // <- value is changed
                    if ((A != AA) && (B != BB))
                        v++; // <- value is changed
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}, [](uint64_t first, uint64_t second)->uint64_t {
    std::cerr << first << ' + ' << second;  // <- wrong values occur
    return first+second;
}
);
```

This is a parallel reduce operation where the initial value is 0. Then, in each parallel computation, based on the initial value, we count up (local variable `v` in the first lambda function). The second lambda function aggregates the results from parallel workers.

Interestingly enough, this code does *not* work as expected. The output of the second lambda function will show enormous figures that result from integer overflows.

The code works correctly when replacing the second line with:

```
uint64_t positive = tbb::parallel_reduce(range, (uint64_t)0, // <- initial value
```

Now I wonder. Wouldn't the definition of the first lambda (`uint64_t v`) enforce this cast and how can a function that is supposed to operate on uint64_t operate on int instead?

The compiler is GCC 6.

Comment: `0` is a `int`...

Comment: Sure thing. But the argument `v` is a `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter what argument the lambda takes. According to [the docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506154), everything is based on the type of the 2nd argument:

```
template<typename Range, typename Value,
         typename Func, typename Reduction>
Value parallel_reduce( const Range& range, const Value& identity,
                       const Func& func, const Reduction& reduction,
                       [, partitioner[, task_group_context& group]] );
```

with pseudo-signatures of:

```
Value Func::operator()(const Range& range, const Value& x)
Value Reduction::operator()(const Value& x, const Value& y)
```

So a `Value` is passed into `Func` and into `Reduction` and returned. If you want `uint64_t`s everywhere, you'll need to ensure that `Value` is `uint64_t`. Which is why your `(uint64_t)0` works but your `0` doesn't (and is actually undefined behavior to boot).

---

Note that this is the same problem that you would get with just normal [`accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
std::vector<uint64_t> vs{0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff};
uint64_t sum = std::accumulate(vs.begin(), vs.end(), 0, std::plus<uint64_t>{});
                                //                  ^^^ oops, int 0!
                                //           even though I'm using plus<uint64_t>!
assert(sum == 0x17ffffffd);     // fails because actually sum is truncated
                                // and is just 0x7ffffffd
```

Comment: Actually, the result of the above example is UB (unsigned -> signed with overflow is UB).

Comment: So to summarize this in a simple way, the lambda function is in-fact calculating on uint64_t, however it is wrapped in an interface that is implicitely defined on  int, therefore there is a cast to int happening in the return of the first lambda and the int is passed to the second lambda, then recast to uint64_t, but the damage has already been done.

Comment: @ypnos Yep, that's basically it.